# Why can't I link "xlnt" library?

Tags: c++, linker

I've scoured *SO* and found some similar questions, but nothing in the answers helped me.
I'm in no way a seasoned `c++` programmer, and it feels like I'm hitting a brick wall with this library.
Though I don't want to give it up, I want to learn how to do it.
Am I missing something basic?

**My steps for building `xlnt` library**:

1. `cmake ..` the source of `xlnt`
2. build it with MSVS 2019 as a `Release x64`

**Sample test code**:

```
#include "xlnt/xlnt.hpp"

int main()
{
    xlnt::workbook wb;
    xlnt::worksheet ws = wb.active_sheet();
    ws.cell("A1").value(5);
    ws.cell("B2").value("string data");
    ws.cell("C3").formula("=RAND()");
    wb.save("example.xlsx");
    return 0;
}
```

**Project properties with `.hpp` and `.lib` directories**:
[image]

**Project properties with dependencies**:
(I've also copied the `xlnt.dll` to the root of my project)
[image]

Errors I get when I try to run the code:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: xlnt-test, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::exception::`vftable'" (??_7exception@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::illegal_character::`vftable'" (??_7illegal_character@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::invalid_attribute::`vftable'" (??_7invalid_attribute@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::invalid_cell_reference::`vftable'" (??_7invalid_cell_reference@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::invalid_column_index::`vftable'" (??_7invalid_column_index@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::invalid_data_type::`vftable'" (??_7invalid_data_type@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::invalid_file::`vftable'" (??_7invalid_file@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::invalid_parameter::`vftable'" (??_7invalid_parameter@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::invalid_sheet_title::`vftable'" (??_7invalid_sheet_title@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::detail::izstream::`vftable'" (??_7izstream@detail@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::key_not_found::`vftable'" (??_7key_not_found@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::missing_number_format::`vftable'" (??_7missing_number_format@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::no_visible_worksheets::`vftable'" (??_7no_visible_worksheets@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::detail::ozstream::`vftable'" (??_7ozstream@detail@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::unhandled_switch_case::`vftable'" (??_7unhandled_switch_case@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::unsupported::`vftable'" (??_7unsupported@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::detail::vector_istreambuf::`vftable'" (??_7vector_istreambuf@detail@xlnt@@6B@)
1>xlnt.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const xlnt::detail::vector_ostreambuf::`vftable'" (??_7vector_ostreambuf@detail@xlnt@@6B@)
1>D:\Docs\Programming\cpp\xlnt-test\x64\Release\xlnt-test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 18 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "xlnt-test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the library for you. It work after dowing this:

1. Downloading source from official website [here](https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt)
2. Create new VS project with CMake
3. Create a new exec project (`MyTestApplication`)
4. Set additional include directories (in my case `G:\CMake\Sources\xlnt-master\include`)
5. In **debug** mode, the genereated library is called `xlntd.lib` (with `d` suffix)

   - Add `..\source\$(Configuration)\xlntd.lib` at `Linker -> Input`
   - $(Configuration) = `Debug` in debug mode
   - You can also define `..\source\$(Configuration)\` as additional library directories and put just `xlntd.lib` as input lib
6. In **Release** mode, the genereated library is called `xlnt.lib`

   - Add `..\source\$(Configuration)\xlnt.lib` at `Linker -> Input`
   - $(Configuration) = `Release` in release mode
   - You can also define `..\source\$(Configuration)\` as additional library directories and put just `xlnt.lib` as input lib

[image]

After dowing this, it should be `OK`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Landstalker!  
Can't believe it wasn't working without adding the `Debug` library, since I was only trying to run on `Release`! >_<